# FB Thinks Meta Tags Are in Body

Tags: html, facebook, meta, document-body

[If you follow this links you will see that there is a paragraph-tag that should not be there in line 3](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://lightningsoul.com/media/vid/amazing/731/TRANSPARENT-CARS-WITH-AUGMENTED-REALITY#content)

This is the actual code that "causes" this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

I do not get why there would be a paragraph-Tag cancelling the  element and making FB believe that meta-tags are in the body instead... do you?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flightningsoul.com%2Fmedia%2Fvid%2Famazing%2F731%2FTRANSPARENT-CARS-WITH-AUGMENTED-REALITY%23content&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 You have a lot of mis-matching tags.

Comment: so which of these explains a p-tag exiting the head?

Comment: There is no “paragraph-tag” in line 3 in the code posted or in the document linked to.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I get this question. First, there is no p that breaks out of the head. Second, what does this have to do with Facebook?

Comment: See the answer Mr Lister.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I used the Facebook Open Graph Debugger to solve the issue. On the very bottom there is a link called

Scraped URL  See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL

This shows exactly what Facebook catches as code and there was a print of a paragraph-tag from one of the libraries I have been using. I can only recommend to debug it this way because I wasted a lot of time not doing so (because I did not see the link at the bottom of the page).